# Network Discovery sample issue in android

Tags: android, android-networking

I am working on a network discovery sample, so downloaded sample application from https://github.com/rorist/android-network-discovery

Its works but if i start application for 5 times it restart my Samsung galaxy tab 2.

Any solution on it or any better sample application for Network discovery in android

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [JmDNS](http://jmdns.sourceforge.net/apidocs/index.html) in my applications without any problems. Android has an [NSD API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/nsd/package-summary.html) since API 16 but it was useless for my purposes since it doesn't expose the DNS TXT records. You can get more details about this at [this bug report](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35810).